# How To Validate a Confirm Password With Regular Expression in IOS

Tags: objective-c, regex, ios7, uitextfield

My password regex is:

```
@"^.{4,32}$"
```

How can I write a confirm password regex that contains above requirements and that is also equal to my password string?

Comment: Why not use above regex for the password field and compare the string of the confirm field to the first password field?

Comment: I have tried regex something like @"(?=^[]{4,32}$)(?=^%@$)" for compare password but its not working. i do not need to compare strings as i am changing string colors in realtime using observers.

Comment: if you just need to compare the password and confirm password then what's the need of using regex. You can simply compare the string like if (![passTextField.text isEqualToString: conformPassTextField.text])